# Find the value of $||T||$ if T is defined as:

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

This question was asked in GATE 2016: Please help me to figure out the right answer.

Let $T$ ∶ $ℓ_2$ → $ℓ_2$ be defined by
$T((x_1,x_2,...,x_n...))$=$(X_2-X_1, X_3-X_2,...,X_{n+1}-x_n,...)$
Then

(A) $||T|| = 1$

(B) $||T||$ > 2 but bounded

(C)$ 1 < ||T|| < 2$

(D)$ ||T||$ is unbounded

I think answer is (A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will not be (a).  Consider
$$
x = (1,-1,0,0,0,\dots)
$$
as a counterexample.  To get an actual upper bound, note that
$$
\|(Tx)\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_{i+1}-x_i|^2} \leq 
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_{i+1}|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i|^2} \leq 2\|x\|
$$