# How this inequality is derived?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $T$ ∶ $ℓ_2$ → $ℓ_2$ be defined by
$T((x_1,x_2,...,x_n...))$=$(X_2-X_1, X_3-X_2,...,X_{n+1}-x_n,...)$
Then I have find the norm of $T$.

Here is the answer to this question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1647794/581242

I am not able to see how this first inequality is derived.

$\|(Tx)\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_{i+1}-x_i|^2} \leq 
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_{i+1}|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i|^2} \leq 2\|x\|$

Comment: Hint: apply Minkowski's inequality.

Comment: The first inequality is wrong. @StammeringMathematician

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for pointing that out. Now I can see it after your answer below.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is this an application of  Minkowski's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there was a small typo. Use the inequality $|a-b|^{2} \leq 2(a^{2}+b^{2})$ . The final result is correct but the first inequality is wrongly stated.